# what he was saying / what he was talking about

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrases, phrase-choice

There is the following sentence in my grammar book:

> John was talking, but nobody was listening to **what he was saying**.

Can I transform it into the next sentence and hold the same meaning?

> John was talking, but nobody was listening to **what he was talking about**.

It seems pretty similar for me in that context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the meaning should stay the same. But they have slightly different meanings. "Talking about" is the general context of what he is talking about. "Saying" is more of the exact words of what he is saying.

Comment: I agree.  To put it a different way, if John says "I really like the [1958 Edsel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edsel#1958)", then those words are what he is *saying*, but the 1958 Edsel is *what he is talking about*.

Comment: @stangdon, DialFrost wrote that "the meaning should stay the same" in that context.

Comment: _Nobody could understand what he was talking about_ would be a more natural use of the phrase.